# Beamer class Georgian language problem

Tags: beamer, languages

when I use article class Georgian language works and I can type without problem,but when I change it to beamer class nothing appears in Georgian. Can anyone help me

```
\documentclass[a4paper,georgian,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sylfaen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
გამარჯობა
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not test myself due to missing font, but there had been similar problem reports where the text was indeed written with beamer, but the textcolour was white. Can you check in your pdf by selecting all (and maybe copy) if the text is hidden?

Comment: I have checked and the text color is black, I changed it to other colors but no use. Thanks anyways

Comment: Since this question does not specifically have to do with bibliographies or `biblatex`, I have removed the tag. If you feel it is appropriate, you should at least explain how in your question.

Comment: No it's inappropriate I had missclicked, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in beamer the sans serif font is used, so you need to set \setsansfont to your font (I used Arial for the example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial Unicode MS}
%\setsansfont{Sylfaen}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
გამარჯობა
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also don't use inputenc along with xelatex or lualatex.