Automatically use fallback font for emoji when generating beamer slides with pandoc
I have a Markdown document including emojis. I try to generate PDF slides using the Beamer package using Pandoc.
Emojis are included in text of the Markdown file and in included SVG images.
I have been trying to instruct lualatex to use a fallback font as described here. Unfortunately this does not work as soon as I use the Beamer package:
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F642) in font [lmsans10-regular]:+tlig;
!

In contrast to, for example, this solution I would like the generation to automatically select an alternative font. I do not want to use TeX commands in the Markdown file.
I invoke Pandoc with
pandoc --standalone --embed-resources -o "$output_dir/$file.pdf" -t beamer --mathml --variable=theme:Dresden --pdf-engine=lualatex $file

I can add TeX code in the header using the --include-in-header option.

Well you are not showing any code that one could use for test, but my crystal ball points to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319785/2388

Recent versions of pandoc allow you to set font fallbacks in the YAML header (or variables respectively):
---
mainfont: NotoSans
mainfontfallback:
  - "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"
---

# Test

Hello emoji 



I previously had pandoc 3.1.3 installed. That one is too old. Apparently this feature has been added with version 3.1.12.
